# Retrieving multiple items with an SQLite query

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to make a simple map making function. I have a database with geographic coordinates ('latitude' and 'longitude'), places names ('feature_names) and the ISO-3166 country codes ('countrycodes'). Now I have gotten this to work with just querying the lat/long and having Folium make my map, but the problem with that is that, well, there are multiple Ottawas, Vancouvers, Londons, etc. in the world. Hence the introduction of the country code to try and narrow things down.

My issue is that I can't seem to get the SQL query to return anything. The code executes without throwing me an error, but does not return anything. 
TL;DR: How do I make multiple queries to my database?

```
cur.execute("SELECT feature_name FROM WorldCities")
locnames = str(cur.fetchall())

cur.execute("SELECT country_code FROM WorldCities")
countrycodes = str(cur.fetchall())

def mapmaker():
location = input(prompt = "Where would you like to go? ")
country = input(prompt = "Great! Do you know which country this is in? ")

if not location:
    input(prompt = "Sorry, I didn't quite get that")

if location in locnames and country in countrycodes:

    #latquery = "SELECT latitude FROM WorldCities WHERE feature_name = ? AND country_code = ?"
    #lat = cur.execute(latquery, (location, ))
    latquery = cur.execute("SELECT latitude FROM WorldCities WHERE feature_name = ? AND country_code = ?", ((location,) (countrycodes,)))
    #lat = cur.execute(latquery, (location, + countrycodes))
    latloc = (latquery.fetchall())

    #longquery = "SELECT longitude FROM WorldCities WHERE feature_name = ?"
    #long = cur.execute(longquery, (location, ))
    #longloc = (long.fetchone())

    print(latloc) #longloc[0], country[0])
    #map = folium.Map(location=(latloc[0], longloc[0]), zoom_start=15)

    #return map
else:
    print ("Sorry, I didn't understand your query")
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't pass a tuple of tuples to the query builder, also you may want to pass the country code, not the whole list, i.e.: `(location, country)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A database can be smarter than a simple flat list of rows. In particular, it can contain indexes to speedup queries. Without knowing if and how the database is indexed, it is not possible to optimize a query.

If your database contains indexes, you should not load its content in flat lists, but instead use direct queries.

That being said, you can retrieve more than one single column from a query, so IMHO the correct way to extract geographic coordinates from you table should be:

```
latlonquery = cur.execute("""SELECT latitude, longitude FROM WorldCities
WHERE feature_name = ? AND country_code = ?""", (location, countrycodes))
lat_lon = latlonquery.fetchone()
if lat_lon is not None:
    lat, lon = lat_lon
    print(lat, lon, location, country)
    ...
```